# C# Sql Helper like ORM

Tags: c#, sql

i Need Collection i am trying this but i need optimize one,

i want to return collection like any ORM so below code to trying
it's working fine but i need more advance one so please guide me this

i trying this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

namespace SqlHelper.Data.sql
{
    public static class SqlHelper
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Execute sp by passing Parameter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="connectionString"></param>
        /// <param name="spName"></param>
        /// <param name="listSqlParameters"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static T ExecuteStoredProcedure<T>(string connectionString, string spName, IList<SqlParameter> listSqlParameters)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 150;

                    foreach (SqlParameter sqlParam in listSqlParameters)
                    {
                        if (sqlParam.DbType == DbType.String || sqlParam.DbType == DbType.AnsiString)
                            if (sqlParam.Value == null)
                            {
                                sqlParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                            }

                        // sqlParam.Value=!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) sqlParam.Value)?sqlParam.Value:DBNull.Value;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
                    }
                    listSqlParameters.Clear();
                    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
                    {
                        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        var ds = new DataSet();
                        conn.Open();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        return ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0
                            ? (T)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]
                            : (T)(object)String.Empty;
                    }
                    if (typeof(T) == typeof(DataTable))
                    {
                        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        var ds = new DataSet();
                        conn.Open();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        ds.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                        return (T)(object)ds.Tables[0];
                    }
                    if (typeof(T) == typeof(DataSet))
                    {
                        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        var ds = new DataSet();
                        conn.Open();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        ds.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                        return (T)(object)ds;
                    }
                    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
                    {

                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        return default(T);

                    }
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return default(T);
                }
            }
        }

        public static ICollection<T> DataTableToList<T>(DataTable table) where T : class, new()
        {
            // AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, T>();
            return table.ToCollection<T>();
            //return AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, IList<T>>(table.CreateDataReader()).ToList();
        }

        internal static ICollection<T> ToCollection<T>(this DataTable dt)
        {
            ICollection<T> lst = new Collection<T>();
            var tClass = typeof(T);
            var pClass = tClass.GetProperties();
            var dc = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList();
            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                var cn = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(tClass);
                var item1 = item;
                foreach (var pc in from pc in pClass let d = dc.Find(c => c.ColumnName == pc.Name) where d != null where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(item1[pc.Name])) select pc)
                {
                    pc.SetValue(cn, item[pc.Name], null);
                }
                lst.Add(cn);
            }
            return lst;
        }
    }
}
```

This code working like :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using SqlHelper.Data.sql;

namespace Demo.Data
{
    public  class BaseDa
    {
        protected static readonly IList<SqlParameter> ListSqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        protected static string ProcQuery;
        protected static string ConnString;


        public static ICollection<CheckClaim> Get(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcQuery = "<sp name>";
                ConnString = "Data Source=<server name>;initial catalog=<db name>;User ID=<user name>;Password=<password>;TrustServerCertificate=True;";

                ListSqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CheckFileID", id));

                var dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteStoredProcedure<DataTable>(ConnString, ProcQuery, ListSqlParameters);
                return SqlHelper.DataTableToList<CheckClaim>(dt);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }

    public class CheckClaim
    {
        public int GroupID { get; set; }
        public int PatientID { get; set; }
        public string PayeeName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your specific problem? There can be plenty of things missing here, depending on how smart your ORM needs to be. You should look at other open source ORMs and see what cases they cover. However, your question is really asking people to finish your library for you (or tell you what it should implement - which is entirely up to *you*)

Comment: i need collection using ADO.net 

so i use above code and working fine but i need optimize code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Dapper(simple object mapper for .net) you can easily get the data in collection with out converting data table into collection you can refer this link for more information

https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Comment: thanks but i need this using ADO.net or using enterprise library